# Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook" to force usage

Tags: android

While using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1'` 
in your gradle, we cannot use miminSdkVersion < 15.

How can solve it?

Comment: I don't understand, is this a kind of self answer or you have a question for us? If you want to provide to us a solution to an issue you have encountered please write a quesion and self-answer your question with the solution

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3404#issue-111362199

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve this error by putting the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="14"
    tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook,yourPackage"/>
```